# Does GAL support ISP?

Tags: isp, pld

In my understanding, GALs are erasable devices, so they are programmable as many times as needed.
Theoretically, ISP should be an option available on them, but I can't find such a device.

Do GALs support ISP?
If yes, which one? Can I have some examples?

Comment: "As many times as needed" was 100, on Lattice GAL16V8.

Comment: There used to be Lattice' *ispGAL22(L)V10*.